# parameterized oracle query with enterprise library

Tags: oracle, c#-3.0, enterprise-library

My .cs file contains this code

```
DbCommand dbc = 
    db.GetStoredProcCommand(
        string.Format(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["INSERT_TBLREPORTTYPE"]
                , rtype, zoneid, name));
```

and my query in web.cofig is:

```
<add key="INSERT_TBLREPORTTYPE" 
    value="INSERT INTO TBLREPORT(ID,TYPE,RELATIONID,ISACTIVE,NAME)    
            VALUES(SEQ_REPORT.NEXTVAL,{0},{1},0,{2}) "/>
```

How to add parameter so that I can prevent sql injection on my site?

I tried

```
db.AddInParameter(dbc, "NAME", DbType.String, name);
db.AddInParameter(dbc, "RELATIONID", DbType.Int32, zoneid);
db.AddInParameter(dbc, "TYPE", DbType.String, rtype);
```

and also

```
dbc.Parameters[0].DbType = DbType.String;
dbc.Parameters[0].Value = name;
dbc.Parameters[1].DbType = DbType.Int32;
dbc.Parameters[1].Value = zoneid;
dbc.Parameters[2].DbType = DbType.String;
dbc.Parameters[2].Value = rtype;
```

None of them is working.  Can anyone give me suggestions regarding this????

Comment: explain 'none of them working...' are you getting errors like ORA-???? ? What happens?

Comment: {"Invalid index 0 for this OracleParameterCollection with Count=0."} System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: I believe the param should be @NAME, @RELATIONID,@TYPE in the query instead of {0},{1},{2}

Comment: none of the above method...ie db.AddInParametee and dbc.Parameter[int index]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter prefix for Oracle is `:`.  So you should change your SQL to:

```
<add key="INSERT_TBLREPORTTYPE" 
    value="INSERT INTO TBLREPORT(ID, TYPE, RELATIONID, ISACTIVE, NAME)    
           VALUES(SEQ_REPORT.NEXTVAL, :TYPE, :RELATIONID, 0, :NAME) "/>
```

Then you can add the parameters using:

```
db.AddInParameter(dbc, ":NAME", DbType.String, name);
```